# CS1061 C# 'Label' does not contain a definition for 'Text

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to C# and I got a task that ask of me to use a label for a result. I keep getting error at commented line:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double a, b, c = 0;

        a = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        b = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);

        switch (comboBox1.Text)
        {
            case "+":
                c = a + b;
                break;
            case "-":
                c = a - b;
                break;
            case "*":
                c = a * b;
                break;
            case "/":
                c = a / b;
                break;
        }

        // error here at .Text
        labelRezultat.Text = c.ToString(); 
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double a;
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double b;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string operacija;
    }
}
```

This is a WPF app in visual studio 2017. I have made 2 text boxes, one button an one combobox. In that combobox are operations for calculating

Comment: Well, a `Label` doesn't have a `Text` property, it does however have a `Content` property.

Answer (score 4):

The `Text` property of label exists in Windows Forms applications.
In `WPF` applications as yours you have the `Content` property:

```
 labelRezultat.Content = c.ToString();
```